# Closest point to a surface using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, optimization, vector-analysis

I know how to solve constrained problems if I am given the surface and the restriction. But I'm a little lost on the application of this for finding the closest point.

Using Lagrange multipliers, how could I find the closest points of $z = x^2-y^2+1$ to the origin? What would be the reasoning for it?

What about if the it was the closest from another set, let's say, the closest points from $y = x$ to $y = x^2+2$. What is the reasoning behind solving these kinds of problems using Lagrange's Multipliers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to minimize the distance from a point $p$ that lies on the surface to the origin.
First, you have three variables $x$, $y$, $z$, i.e. the three coordinates of the point $p$.

Second, the objective function is
$$
f(x,y,z) = (x-0)^2+ (y-0)^2 + (z-0)^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2.
$$
Note that we use the distance *squared*. This is because the distance squared is minimal if and only if the distance is minimal. But the distance squared function makes the calculations easier; there is no square root, so the derivative becomes easier. This is a standard trick.

And finally, the constraint is given by $g(x,y,z) = x^2 - y^2 + 1 - z = 0$, which is basically the equation for the surface.
Now you can write down the Lagrangian function $L(x,y,z,\lambda) = f(x,y,z) - \lambda g(x,y,z)$ and proceed to solve the problem.

Your second problem goes as follows: We have two points $p$ and $q$, each lying on a surface. What is their minimal distance? This problem is basically the same, but you have more variables and constraints.

First, you have 6 variables, namely 3 for the point $p=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and 3 for the point $q=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$.
The objective function now becomes $f(x_1,\ldots,z_2)=(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2 + (z_1-z_2)^2$. And finally, there are two constraints, namely $g(x_1,y_1,z_1)=x_1-y_1 = 0$ and $h(x_2,y_2,z_2)=x_2+2 - y_2 = 0$.
Now the Lagrangian becomes
$$ L(x_1,\ldots,z_2,\lambda,\mu) = f(x_1,\ldots,z_2) - \lambda g(x_1,y_1,z_1) - \mu h(x_2,y_2,z_2).$$